# state_machine validations on transitions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, state-machine

Using the state_machine gem, I want to have validations that run only on transitions. For example:

```
# Configured elsewhere:
# StateMachine::Callback.bind_to_object = true

class Walrus > ActiveRecord::Base
  state_machine :life_cycle, :initial => :fetus do
    state :fetus
    state :child
    state :adult
    state :dead

    event :coming_of_age do
      transition :child => :adult
    end


    before_transition :child => :adult do
      validate :coming_of_age_party_in_the_future
    end
  end
end
```

If I attach that validation to the adult state, it will fail once that date passes. But I only need it to be valid during the transition. I could add something like:

```
validate :coming_of_age_party_in_the_future, if: 'adult? && life_cycle_was == "child"'
```

but that seems to miss the point of transitions.

Also, since I am binding to the object in callbacks, how would it conditionally call 'validate', a class method? (Binding is necessary since many methods in callbacks are private.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using the `transition if: :x` feature?

It should work something like this:

```
event :coming_of_age do
  transition :child => :adult, if: :coming_of_age_party_in_the_future
end
```

You can see the section 'Class definition' in 'Example' (near the top) or 'Transition context' in 'Syntax flexibility' (pretty far down) in the [README](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine)

Comment: What if I have a number of these? Are rails validators out of the question if I want to validate transitions? Seems like a pretty common use case

Comment: Technically it's not. You could craft one method that holds all validations nested in a case statement, or do it the way you mentioned, but, I assume you want to disallow/prevent the transition itself, and so I advocate putting the 'guarding' logic in place with the transition - if only for readability reasons.

Comment: 'In that case is it better to add custom methods that check for transitions? Like `life_cycle_was == 'child' && adult?`

Comment: Validations, to me, are rather to ensure consitency and correctness. A construct related to persisting data, not so much manipulating it and state machines, transitions in particular are about manipulation, so should use their own protection mechanism. But that's debatable personal taste.

Comment: I value individual methods over one big cover-it-all construct. Small individual ones are easier to read and to debug. So, if you go with validations, go with those

Comment: Yeah we have a lot of self-contained validations, but seeing 5 in a row that check for transitioning smells bad. Especially when adopting a state machine to clean up those transitions. I think the if condition should be something like `if: :eligible_for_adulthood` which then breaks down all of the validations.

Comment: If the conditions are adequately concise, you could just do `if: lambda { |thing| conditional }`.